# CreateJob for Azure Data Lake Analytics from C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-lake

I am trying to create a Job using the C# api and the DataLakeAnalyticsJobManagementClient and have been unsuccessful in every attempt with the error message: **"Invalid job definition."**. There is no other useful information about what is invalid about it.  The job is a U-SQL job and I began bey creating it in the azure portal and that worked just fine and ran correctly with no errors.

I am building up the JobInformation and JobProperties using the same information that the portal test one used and I know the U-SQL statements are valid.

```
JobProperties props = new JobProperties(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\myusqlscript.usql"));
var myId = Guid.NewGuid();
JobInformation jobNfo = new JobInformation("mysamplejob", JobType.USql, props,myId) { DegreeOfParallelism = 1, Priority = 1000};

jobNfo.Validate();  //<--this doesn't throw an exception either

var jobs = await _adlaJobClient.Job.ListAsync("myanalyticsaccountname");
var adlaJob = await _adlaJobClient.Job.CreateAsync("myanalyticsaccountname", myId, jobNfo);
```

I have tried various combinations of constructors and property settings including just using defaults for some of the properties and I get the same result: **"Invalid job definition."** There is no other info that would indicate missing information or formatting issues or anything like that.

Anyone out there created Azure Data Lake Analytics jobs with the C# API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyone out there created Azure Data Lake Analytics jobs with the C# API?

You need to use USqlJobProperties instead of JobProperties.

```
var props = new USqlJobProperties(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\myusqlscript.usql"));
```

The official document for [Data Lake analytics get started .NET SDK](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-get-started-net-sdk.md) is not available. But we can also get some useful sample code from the [histories](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/commit/5f3e00a18a13dc20e747e0670a47a5ef7094f94b) of this document.

```
public static Guid SubmitJobByPath(string scriptPath, string jobName)
{
    var script = File.ReadAllText(scriptPath);
    var jobId = Guid.NewGuid();
    var properties = new USqlJobProperties(script);
    var parameters = new JobInformation(jobName, JobType.USql, properties, priority: 1, degreeOfParallelism: 1, jobId: jobId);
    var jobInfo = _adlaJobClient.Job.Create(_adlaAccountName, jobId, parameters);
    return jobId;
}
```

Comment: Bingo! that did the trick!  just changed JobProperties to USqlJobProperties and it worked.  Thanks.

Comment: Updates link for docs : https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-manage-use-dotnet-sdk.md